# Monotouch Dynamic Proxy Exception on WCF Wrapper

Tags: c#, ios, wcf, proxy, xamarin

I am developing an ios application in Xamarin C#

I have created a common project for android/ios. Its a WCF wrapper. Well, an exception occurs

> System.InvalidOperationException: MonoTouch does not support dynamic
>   proxy code generation. Override this method or its caller to return
>   specific client proxy instance

I do not understand why I get this exception. Because my goal is separating ios project and wcf service thats why I have created WCF wrapper.

On here http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/
says that, can create a proxy with a tool. But I do not want to use kind of things..

This is  wcf wrapper side

```
    public string LoginDmServer(WCFLoginInfo lib)
    {

        var logininfo = new LoginInfo();
        logininfo.LibraryName = lib.Library;
        logininfo.Password = lib.Password;
        logininfo.ServerName = lib.ServerUrl;
        logininfo.Username = lib.Username;

        serviceLibrary.LoginInfo = logininfo;


        service.Login(ref serviceLibrary);
       lib.DST = serviceLibrary.Dst;

        return lib.DST;
    }
```

the exception occurs on

```
        service.Login(ref serviceLibrary);
```

And here is ios side

```
        btnConnectServer.TouchUpInside += async (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            service = new WCFService();

          var result=  service.LoginDmServer(new WCFLoginInfo(txtLibraryName.Text,
           txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text,
                txtServerUrl.Text));

            if (result == null)
            {

            }

         }
```

Comment: something does add up in those code samples ... can you clean them up (there an uncommented `txtUserName.txt,...` for example in the last one, and where is `WCFService`?

Comment: @Noctis, I cleaned the comments, well, in the last one is on ios project. And it refers to WCF wrapper that is called "WCF Service" by me. Real WCF servise is on Wrapper. iOS project just creates an instance of WCF wrapper. Thank you for your comment.